# Trying to create a TIMESTAMP type, the NOW() function is not working on my Azure DATA studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-timestamp

```sql
CREATE TABLE comments (
    content VARCHAR(100),
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()  
);
```

The error message

> 'NOW' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Please add the full error message (including the error code) and the result of select version();

Comment: Started executing query at Line 1
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 3
'NOW' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10 is a sql-server error message and is correctly telling you that now() does not exist. - I think sql-server equivalent is getdate() or you are pointing to the wrong server..

Comment: The tsql TIMESTAMP datatype is likely not what you want. That is a deprecated datatype and is now just a synonym for [ROWVERSION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) - which has no relationship to date or time.

Answer (score 0):

`NOW()` is **not ansi-standard sql**.

Given this is a SQL Server error message, I'll say that SQL Server people tend to use `getdate()` instead. However, the actual standard is `current_timestamp`, which FWIW is supported on both SQL Server and whichever of MySql or Posgresql you were using before, albeit they both treat is as a function (you need parentheses) while SQL Server treats it as a keyword (no parentheses).